# Anonymous function error on Google Maps API marker click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, foursquare

Using Foursquare Google Maps APIs, my goal is to use the venue photo property provided by Foursquare and, if it's available in a venue's metadata, to render it along with the venue's name within the Google Maps API info window. 
If only one of the two properties are available, I want to render the available one only. If the venueInfo is undefined or neither property is available, I want to simply display "No info available" in the info window. I tried doing this with a conditional operator with multiple conditions.

For at least one marker, sometimes the info will display, but sometimes I get these errors.

[image]

I don't understand what's wrong or how to fix it. If the 'name' property is undefined, shouldn't the conditional just make it fall back to display "No info available"? And if the info for the marker displayed fine previously, how can it stop working when I click the same marker again?

Here's my conditional statement for rendering inside the info window:

```
            <InfoWindow>
        {venueInfo.name && venueInfo.bestPhoto ?
          <Fragment>
            <p>{venueInfo.name}</p>
            <img src={`${venueInfo.bestPhoto.prefix}200x200${venueInfo.bestPhoto.suffix}`}
            alt={"Venue"}
            />
          </Fragment> : venueInfo.name ? <p>{venueInfo.name}</p> : venueInfo && venueInfo.bestPhoto ? <img    src={`${venueInfo.bestPhoto.prefix}200x200${venueInfo.bestPhoto.suffix}`}
          // Screen readers already announce as image; don't need the word "image", "photo", etc.
          alt={"Venue"}
        /> : <p>No info available</p>}
      </InfoWindow>
```

For reference here's the [full component code](https://github.com/nataliecardot/react-neighborhood-map/blob/master/src/components/map.js) on GitHub.

Comment: venueInfo is undefined you need to log output of                    
props.venues.find(venue => venue.id === marker.id);

Comment: your props does not contain a venue whose id matches with marker.id

Comment: If clicking the same marker worked before (the venue and marker ID were correctly associated), how could it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is caused by trying to access a property of a value which is undefined.

What that means in your case is that `venueInfo` is actually undefined when trying to access `venuInfo.bestPhoto`. Which would cause the crash and not the conditional operator.

Comment: I have an 'else' condition to render "No info available" if none of the previous conditions are met. Would that cover the case of venueInfo being undefined? I also tried adding a special condition to render that text if typeof venueInfo == undefined but still got the error.

Comment: No. The first statement is still evaluated. Thats why the code still crashes when trying to access property `name` of undefined. I would recommend doing a check to see if `venuInfo` has a value and only then access its properties

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this output, you filter the prop.venues to get venueInfo,so first check venueInfo to confirm whether it has the property of bestPhoto and check props.markers in line 13 to confirm the marker.id property.

```
const venueInfo = props.venues.find(venue => venue.id === marker.id);
```

Sometimes "the photo for that marker displays normally",I think the problem still because of props, the photo property is correct sometimes,so it works fine.

Comment: It seems like since I was able to click a marker without errors before, it couldn't be a problem with the marker/venue ID. Also I check if it has the bestPhoto property in my conditional.